# Method of characteristics and partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can solve PDEs by method of characteristics but the one below is so mixed that I tried alot but just could not do it.
Can anyone give a hint or some steps towards the solution of the following problem:
$$(1+x^2) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} + (3 - 2xy) \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = \frac{10}{\sqrt{y}}- ( \frac{9}{2y}+x)H$$
Where $H$ is function of $x$ and $y.$

Help would be really appreciable if what to do with such mixed equation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first constant of integration:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x^2+1}=\dfrac {dy}{3-2xy}$$
$$y'{(x^2+1)}={3-2xy}$$
$$y'x^2+2xy+y'=3$$
$$(x^2y)'+y'=3$$
Integrate:
$$C_1=x^2y+y-3x$$
You have now $y$ as a function of $x$ :
$$y=\dfrac {C_1+3x}{x^2+1}$$
You can use this result for the second constant of integration:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x^2+1}=\dfrac {dz}{ \frac{10}{\sqrt{y}}- ( \frac{9}{2y}+x)z}$$
The integral won't be easy to evaluate.
$$\frac{10}{\sqrt{y}}- \left( \frac{9}{2y}+x\right)z=z'(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Ok but now to find the next constant is even more difficult. As I see it becomes more complicated. Have you also tried to find the other constant.

Comment: Yes it's more complicated because the functions invovlved are not easy. But the method of characteristics works fine. It's the integral that is hard to evaluate. @Mathslovershah

Comment: Yes this is ok now. Thank you for your time. I got what you mean and it is really helpful. Thanks once again

Comment: You're welcome @Mathslovershah